# json function not call via using jquery ajax mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller

I am using model pop-up and I want to call controller but json function not calling. when I use a breakpoint in jquery data fill in the textbox but function not call. kindly tell me where I am wrong.

first, I declare a variable then store password textbox value then pass password parameter then I click save and using breakpoint message show undefine and I remove previous code then I use this code its not calling function.

Javascript

```
<script>
function mSavePassword() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ChangePassword")",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        data: {
            Password: $('#txtcurrentpassword').val(),
            NewPassword: $('#txtpassword').val(),
            ConfirmPassword: $('#txtConformPassword').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Record) {
            alert("Record  Inserted Successfully");
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

JSON FUNCTION

```
 public JsonResult ChangePassword(User U)
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(constring);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select User_password from BriskSecurity.dbo.Users where User_Id=" + Session["AgentID"] + "", con);
                string mPwd = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                if (Cryptographer.Encrypt(U.Password.Trim()) != mPwd.Trim())
                {
                    TempData["old"] = "Incorrect Password";
                    return Json(TempData["old"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }

                if (U.NewPassword.Trim() != U.ConfirmPassword.Trim())
                {
                    TempData["Wrong"] = "Your New Password and Confirm Password do not match";
                    return Json(TempData["Wrong"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                U.ConfirmPassword = Cryptographer.Encrypt(U.ConfirmPassword);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update BriskSecurity.dbo.Users set User_password='" + U.ConfirmPassword + "' where User_ID=" + Session["AgentID"] + "", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                TempData["PSuccess"] = "Your password has been changed successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Password not changed due to an error Try Again";
                return Json(TempData["Error"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                throw;
            }

            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Comment: `"@Url.Action("ChangePassword")",` that looks broken

Comment: i also use this url: Home/ChangePassword

Comment: but not working

Comment: Are you meaning to use "GET" or should you be using "POST" ?

Comment: No. Not working when i use POST

Comment: Are there even requests being sent back to the back end? In chrome you can check the network tab in the developer console, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest way to send dynamic url to ajax javscript from C# MVC page.

I very easy to use a form like:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("ChangePassword")">
   <input ... />
   <input ..../>

   <input type="submit" value="Change password" />
 </form>
```

and with jQuery:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
   mSavePassword($(this));
});


function mSavePassword($form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop("action"),
        type: $form.prop("method"),
        data: {
            Password: $('#txtcurrentpassword').val(),
            NewPassword: $('#txtpassword').val(),
            ConfirmPassword: $('#txtConformPassword').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (record) {
            alert("Record  Inserted Successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

and do changes on server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ChangePassword(User U)
```

otherwise, won't work

Comment: function called but parameter value does not pass in json function like Password, NewPassword, ConfirmPassword show null.

Comment: how `User` class looks like ? And try to remove `contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",`